# Given a pandas dataframe, how to check and count if a row string is inside a row of nested lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Consider this pandas df:

In:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['the quick brown fox','hi hello','hello there','good morning'], 
                   'col2': [[['the quick brown fox'],['this is a test'], ['how is it going']],
                            ['lore lipsum dolor'],
                            [''],[['good'],['morning']]]})
df
```

Out:

```
    col1                      col2
0   the quick brown fox     [[the quick brown fox], [this is a test], [how is it going]]
1   hi hello                [lore lipsum dolor]
2   hello there                  []
3   good morning            [[good], [morning]]
```

How can I check if the full string of `col1` is inside any of the lists inside `col2` nested lists? For example the expected output should look a new column like this:

In:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col3':[[1,0,0,0],[0],[0], [[0],[0]]]})
df
```

Out:

```
      col3
0   [1, 0, 0]
1   [0]
2   [0]
3   [0, 0]
```

For example tried and would like to apply this idea to my df columns:

```
s = 'the quick brown fox'
l = [['the quick brown fox'],['this is a test'], ['how is it going']]

    a_lis = []
    for e in l:
        if s in e:
            a_lis.append(1)
        else:
            a_lis.append(0)

    print(a_lis)
```

Comment: In second row `[lore lipsum dolor]` is not `[[lore lipsum dolor]]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension with `in` and convert boolean to integer:

```
df['col3'] = [[int(a in x) for x in b] for a, b in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])]

print (df)
                  col1                                               col2  \
0  the quick brown fox  [[the quick brown fox], [this is a test], [how...   
1             hi hello                                [lore lipsum dolor]   
2          hello there                                                 []   
3         good morning                                [[good], [morning]]   

        col3  
0  [1, 0, 0]  
1        [0]  
2        [0]  
3     [0, 0]
```